# Close Connection on completion in SSIS

Tags: ssis, dts

anybody aware of "Close Connection on completion" option in DTS.

I am searching for the equivalent option for OLEDBDestinationTask in SSIS.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question directly: this is done automatically.

The SSIS Connection Manager behaves differently to the way the DTS Connection works. The Connection Managers maintain a pool of connections. Each task that utilises the Connection Manager will get its own connection to the data source - in comparison to DTS, where if the same connection object is used, the same physical connection will be maintained throughout the package.

Apart from that, you can actually make the SSIS Connection Manager behave like a DTS Connection by setting **RetainSameConnection=True**

Comment: Thanks Milen for response..somehow connection was not closing it self so I was searching this option. Will debug more on this...

Comment: @Sanjay did you find a solution?  I am having a similar problem.